# Why Pandas_udf in pyspark is giving the error as below

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I get a SparkException when I execute this code:

```
@pandas_udf('double', PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
def pandas_plus_one(a):
    return a + 1
df.withColumn('v2', pandas_plus_one(df.a)).show()
```

This is the schema of my dataset

```
 |-- a: double (nullable = true)
 |-- b: double (nullable = true)
 |-- c: double (nullable = true)
 |-- d: double (nullable = true)
 |-- TARGET: string (nullable = true)
```

This is the error what I got while executing the above code snippet

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2933.showString. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 475.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task
>   0.3 in stage 475.0 (TID 7841, s6.congolop.com, executor 2): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException    at
>   java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:334)     at
>   org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.message.MessageChannelReader.readNextMessage(MessageChannelReader.java:64)
>     at
>   org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.message.MessageSerializer.deserializeSchema(MessageSerializer.java:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowStreamReader.readSchema(ArrowStreamReader.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowReader.initialize(ArrowReader.java:181)
>     at
>   org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowReader.ensureInitialized(ArrowReader.java:172)
>     at
>   org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowReader.getVectorSchemaRoot(ArrowReader.java:65)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:161)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:121)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:284)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowEvalPythonExec$$anon$2.(ArrowEvalPythonExec.scala:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowEvalPythonExec.evaluate(ArrowEvalPythonExec.scala:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(EvalPythonExec.scala:131)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(EvalPythonExec.scala:93)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Driver stacktrace:    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1651)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1639)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1638)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1638)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
>     at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1872)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1821)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1810)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2034)    at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2055)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2074)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:363)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3278)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2489)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2489)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3259)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3258)  at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2489)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2703)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:254)    at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor84.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException    at
>   java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:334)     at
>   org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.message.MessageChannelReader.readNextMessage(MessageChannelReader.java:64)
>     at
>   org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.message.MessageSerializer.deserializeSchema(MessageSerializer.java:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowStreamReader.readSchema(ArrowStreamReader.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowReader.initialize(ArrowReader.java:181)
>     at
>   org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowReader.ensureInitialized(ArrowReader.java:172)
>     at
>   org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowReader.getVectorSchemaRoot(ArrowReader.java:65)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:161)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:121)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:284)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowEvalPythonExec$$anon$2.(ArrowEvalPythonExec.scala:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowEvalPythonExec.evaluate(ArrowEvalPythonExec.scala:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(EvalPythonExec.scala:131)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(EvalPythonExec.scala:93)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>
> > java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> >     ... 1 more
>
> (, Py4JJavaError(u'An error
>   occurred while calling o2933.showString.\n', JavaObject id=o2934),
>   )

Any idea how can I solve it?

Comment: why aren't you using pyspark udf? `plus_one= F.udf(pandas_plus_one, DoubleType())` and `df = df.withColumn('v2', plus_one('a'))`

Comment: I want to run the my PYTHON code in a distributed environment.  So I want to use pandas udf.

Comment: distributed environment is the literal porpose definition of pyspark, use that.

Comment: By adding ARROW_PRE_0_15_IPC_FORMAT=1 in spark-env.sh  helped me